# Проблемы с UNIX датой php

Tags: php

Проблемы с UNIX Time.

Есть скрипт:

```
date("l",strtotime("11/12/2011 16:39"));
```

пишет, что Суббота. Но сегодня воскресенье. Или

```
date("w",strtotime("11/12/2011 14:28"));
```

тоже Суббота. ( Помогите. А если написать

```
date("l",time()) или date("w",time())
```

- Воскресенье(0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше использовать timestamp() :)

[time()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.time.php)

[getdate()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.getdate.php)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую )